# what is the coffeescript equivalent for this

Tags: coffeescript

I lost the coffee file..so I am trying to trace back the js file to coffee and I use js2coffee site to do it...but this code is confusing.. I don't remember what I wrote in coffee

```
  function PersonalEdit() {
    this.changeNR = __bind(this.changeNR, this);
    this.changeDisability = __bind(this.changeDisability, this);
    this.changeMaritalStatus = __bind(this.changeMaritalStatus, this);
    return PersonalEdit.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
  }
```

I can trace back the function to a constructor

```
    constructor: ->
        super
```

what is about the __bind..I know they are generated for fat arrow.but how can this be in the constructor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those bindings were generated from [fat arrows `=>`](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) in class methods definition.

So, your class looked something like this:

```coffee
class PersonalEdit
  constructor: ->
    super

  changeNR: =>
    # ...

  changeDisability: =>
    # ...

  changeMaritalStatus: =>
    # ...
```